# Message type system for multiple users

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have an idea for a project that will allow users in Windows to request access to a directory using a message type system. As an example, assume that there are 30 users in a Windows Server environment. Two users have the ability to grant access to a Windows Directory. I want to create a program that allows users to request the access by selecting the directory from a drop down box. The request is then sent to both people who have the ability to grant access. I am imagining some pop-up will come up near the task bar to alert the user of this request. Once granted, the initiating user will be alerted and the request will be cleared (or logged into some file).

I have a bit of C# experience and DB experience with SQL, however I am not sure how I will go about running the back end and handling of messages. I was thinking I could store the requests in a SQL database (two fields - Directory and Requesting user ID) and make it refresh the table into the program every 5 mins but this seems a bit overkill. Is there an easier way to do this? No need to worry about security of the file or database.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Someone did this for you decades ago. You can just send an email.

Comment: haha yeah, thats what we have been using. However, what I didn't mention is that the person has to provide access to multiple databases as well as Windows folders - you can see how this can become time consuming with multiple users requesting access. Hopefully my solution will speed this process up by performing it automatically once granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decided to create a file for each request in a directory which is then scanned on a fixed frequency by the program. Seems easier this way given the small number of users and then I won't be wasting resources by opening database connections every 2 minutes.